# Link Sheets and Query with timestamps

Tags: google-sheets, google-bigquery

I'm trying to link a custom query, but since i'm new in this, i'm getting stuck when Sheets tries to read timestamps

I'm getting the following error:

Something's wrong. Please try again later: Error while parsing the query: Syntax error: Table name contains '-' character. It needs to be quoted: 'xxxxxxxxxx' [at 3:10]

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT sequence) as aaaaaaaa,bbbbbbb,
    EXTRACT (date from CreationDateBR) as data,
    FROM xxxxxxxxxxxx
    WHERE CreationDateBR BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2022-01-01'
    AND loja IN ('Marketplace C')
    AND parceiros NOT IN ('partner A')
GROUP BY parceiros,data
ORDER BY data,parceiros asc
```

Comment: The error is explicit, the "-" character in the table name (which you show as "xxxxxxxx") needs to be escaped. What is your table's name? And where is the code to put this response in Sheets?

Answer (score 0):

The error message states that the issue is in the table name. You can try to put backticks around it (**`**):

```
FROM `xxxxxxxxxxxx`
```

A good trick to ensure the proper formatting is to go to your table in the BigQuery UI and click on "query this table": the proper formatting will open in a new query editor.